# Right way to get username and password from connection string?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-2.0, connection-string

I have a connection string like this:

```
"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=tree;UID=root;PASSWORD=branch;Min Pool Size = 0;Max Pool Size=200"
```

How do I get the various database parameters out of it? I can get database name and server like this:

```
serverName = conObject.DataSource;
dbName = conObject.Database;
```

I need the username and password as well similarly. No property is set on the MySqlConnection object.

At present I do it like this:

```
public static void GetDatabaseParameters(string connectionString, out string serverName, out string dbName, out string userName, out string password)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(connectionString, "SERVER=(.*?);DATABASE=(.*?);UID=(.*?);PASSWORD=(.*?);.*");

    //serverName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    //dbName = m.Groups[2].Value;
    userName = m.Groups[3].Value;
    password = m.Groups[4].Value;
}
```

Is there an accepted practice here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) Class

```
string conString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=tree;UID=root;PASSWORD=branch;Min Pool Size = 0;Max Pool Size=200";
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);
string user = builder.UserID;
string pass = builder.Password;
```

Comment: does this work well for mysql as well?

Comment: If you use special .NET components for MySQL, then there should be specific ConnectionStringBuilder, e.g. MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Comment: It would if you had a MySqlConnectionStringBuilder class which is not a default part of the framework. see here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,60345

Comment: how to get DatabaseName out of that , i didn't find any property like that in builder?

Comment: @ImranRizvi `builder.Database` would give it for MySQL connector

Comment: Appears to still work in .NET Core.