# How to get Database Name from Connection String using SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

I do not want to split connection strings using string manipulation functions to get Server, Database, Username, and Password.

I read the following link and read the accepted answer, I found that is the best way to get username and password out from connection string, but what about Database Name?

[Right way to get username and password from connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975122/right-way-to-get-username-and-password-from-connection-string)

How to get Database Name from Connection String using SqlConnectionStringBuilder. (does the DataSource is the Server name?)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

See [MSDN documentation for InitialCatalog Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx):

> Gets or sets the name of the database associated with the connection...
>
> This property corresponds to the "Initial Catalog" and "database" keys within the connection string...

Answer (score 178):

You can use the provider-specific ConnectionStringBuilder class (within the appropriate namespace), or `System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder` to abstract the connection string object if you need to. You'd need to know the provider-specific keywords used to designate the information you're looking for, but for a SQL Server example you could do either of these two things:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string server = builder.DataSource;
string database = builder.InitialCatalog;
```

or

```
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.ConnectionString = connectionString;

string server = builder["Data Source"] as string;
string database = builder["Initial Catalog"] as string;
```

Comment: For me, the last line needed to be:  `string database = builder["Initial Catalog"] as string;` - "Database" was an invalid keyword.

Comment: @Sandra yes ur correct. builder["Database"] as string will work if we use SqlConnectionStringBuilder .

Answer (score 42):

A much simpler alternative is to get the information from the connection object itself. For example:

```
IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var dbName = connection.Database;
```

Similarly you can get the server name as well from the connection object.

```
DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var server = connection.DataSource;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This becomes specific for `SqlConnection`. Is there any similar way out to make this cross RDBMS?

Comment: @AmitJoshi Shouldnt they all implement `IDbConnection`?

Comment: @nawfal: I agree but that still does not make it usable. I have explained this in details in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47727524/5779732

Comment: It can get Database and the DataSource, but couldn't get the userId and the password in this way.

Comment: If [you're using EntityFramework (Core), you can get the information from the `DbContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42638395/15488899).

Answer (score 13):

```
string connectString = "Data Source=(local);" + "Integrated Security=true";

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

Console.WriteLine("builder.InitialCatalog = " + builder.InitialCatalog);
```

Answer (score 7):

this gives you the Xact;

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

connBuilder.ConnectionString = connectionString;

string server = connBuilder.DataSource;           //-> this gives you the Server name.
string database = connBuilder.InitialCatalog;     //-> this gives you the Db name.
```

Answer (score 5):

Database name is a value of [SqlConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx) property.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [InitialCatalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.initialcatalog.aspx) Property or `builder["Database"]` works as well. I tested it with different case and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net EF Core

```
using (var dbContext = new AppDbContext(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>>()))
{
  var dbConnection = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();

  //var serverName = dbConnection.DataSource;
  //var databaseName = dbConnection.Database;
}
```