# How to get machine address from DBConnectionString?

Tags: c#, vb.net, connection-string

I need `machine` address extracted from `DbConnectionString`. I see good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550541/how-to-get-database-name-from-connection-string-using-sqlconnectionstringbuilder) using [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class. My problem is that if I have `named instance` then the `machine` name (inside `DataSource` property) and `SQL instance` will be different. I can make `split` by `\` and take 1st part.
Is there any other more "elegant" way to do that?

Comment: What could be more elegant than var machineAddress = myConnectionString.Split('\')[0].ToString(); ?

Comment: Maybe you want regular expression split Regex.Split(connStr, "DataSource");

Comment: 10x, @markp3rry. You are right. I was wondering if there a special property, but it is not needed.