# ASP.NET EntityFramework get database name

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I created an ASP.NET EF application with MySQL using the following tutorial: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider Its working but I don't like to set the name of my database hardcoded in the MySqlInitializer class - called *myDatabaseName* in the following snippet:

```
var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
        string.Format(
          "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
          "myDatabaseName"));
```

I'm looking for a way to get the name of the database from the DbContext dynamically so that I store the database-name only in the connection-string and not a second time in my MySqlInitializer. But I can't find any attribute for the name, neither in the DbContext nor in the Database-attribute of the DbContext.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should do the job for you  (works up to .NET 6)

```
string databaseName = context.Database.Connection.Database;
```

Comment: Does not work with .NET 7.0 anymore.

Answer (score 91):

For those of you who are using EF core can do this as an alternative:

```
var databaseName = context.Database.GetDbConnection().Database
```

Comment: This is not up to date with EF Core 5.0

Comment: @DMXDavidCardinal What has changed in EF Core 5.0?

Comment: I never used the previous versions so I can't really compare effectively, but the `DbContext.Database` property is of type `DatabaseFacade` which does not contain the method `GetDbConnection()`. The SQL Connection is now defined in a protected `OnConfiguring` method using a `DbContextOptionsBuilder`. However, this optionsBuilder doesnt not seem to be accessible outside the DbContext class.

Comment: @DMXDavidCardinal It doesn't include the method because it's an extension method.  See the [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-5.0#extension-methods)

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Sounds pertinent enough to add to the solution IMO

Comment: make sure you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`, otherwise you won't have `GetDbConnection()` method available.