# Extract properties from a connection string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

In `C#` I am trying to get the `Data Source` and `initial catalog` properties from a connection string.

So if I have

```
metadata=res://*/model.csdl|res://*/model.ssdl|res://*/model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=myDESKTOP;initial catalog=dbName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
```

How can I extract just the values `myDESKTOP` and `dbName` regardless of case on the left hand of the expression?

Comment: Why regex when you can do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/10550705/2093880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dissect your connection string for Entity Framework and extract the internal basic connection string. At that point the SqlConnectionStringBuilder could give you the individual parts that compose the connection string

```
string test = "metadata=res://*/model.csdl|res://*/model.ssdl|res://*/model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source = myDESKTOP; initial catalog = dbName; integrated security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True; App = EntityFramework";

string con = string.Join("=", 
                    string.Join(";", test.Split(';').Skip(2))
                          .Split('=').Skip(1)).Trim('"');

SqlConnectionStringBuilder sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(con);
Console.WriteLine(sb.DataSource);
Console.WriteLine(sb.InitialCatalog);
```