# How to display database name from connectionStrings onto my webpage for development purpose?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

For development purposes I want to display the database it is connected to since I have 1 for development and 1 for production use. How do I do that using either Javascript, html or c#?

Right now I am connected via c#

```
 protected MysqlDbContext db = new MysqlDbContext();
 public class MysqlDbContext: DbContext
 {
     public MysqlDbContext() : base("MysqlDbContext")
     {
     }
 }

 var a = db.Database.Connection.Database.ToString(); //returns me the database name
```

So how can I access the a from my cshtml file?

Comment: if you are using sql you can use connection string builder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550541/how-to-get-database-name-from-connection-string-using-sqlconnectionstringbuilder

Comment: Is there a way to do it from the front end with javascript or html?

Comment: I would guess that you are not connecting to a database from javascript directly so then the answer would be no.  Please update your question with information on what database tech and what you are using to connect to the database

Comment: yes edited, i am currently connected using c#

Comment: @BonBon you need to expose it into the front end before you can display it

Comment: how do i do that exposing part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
    MysqlDbContext db = new MysqlDbContext();
    var dbName = db.Database.Connection.Database.ToString();
}
```

I figured out that using razor syntax to declare my db context and get the name I was able to display it with `<a>@dbName</a>.`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are using Entity Framework. So I will answer that.

In EF core you can get the connection string like this:

```
var dbName = MysqlDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Database;
```

in EF for .net framework:

```
public class MysqlDbContext: DbContext
{
     public MysqlDbContext() : base("MysqlDbContext")
     {
     }

     public string GetDatabaseName()
     {
         return MysqlDbContext.Database.Connection.Database;
     }
}
```

And in your controller you get your context as you normally do and then just access this method.

Comment: yes yes i reached this part but because I was not the one who developed this project, I'm kind of new to EF, so not sure how can I expose the variable such that I can access it under cshtml file.

Comment: Actually I have that Get Name function already, I am left with figuring out how to call the function in my cshtml file.

Comment: Don't you have some controller pulling from the database? there you can access the setting. For a start you can put it in an application variable and then access that variable (@HttpContext.Current.Application["MyDatabaseName"]) from your cshtml file. This is of course hacky